# docker-compose does not load up data

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I have an existing neo4j image with data in it that I run using the following `docker run` command

`docker run --publish=7474:7474 --volume=$HOME/neo4jdev/data:/data neo4j`

When I check this in my browser at `http://192.168.99.100:7474/browser/`, I confirmed that my container has existing nodes in it.

What I want to do is use `docker-compose` instead of `docker run` to run my services. This is what my `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
version: '2'
services:
  neo4jdev:
    image: neo4j
    ports: 
         - "7474:7474"
    volumes: 
         - $HOME/neo4jdev/data
```

I run this using `docker-compose up`.

But when I check my browser, I get an empty database without nodes in it. It seems to only load the latest neo4j image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead

```
volumes:
  - $HOME/neo4jdev/data:/data
```

So your docker-compose.yml would look like this

```
version: '2'
services:
  neo4jdev:
    container_name: n4j
    image: neo4j
    ports: 
         - "7474:7474"
    volumes: 
         - $HOME/neo4jdev/data:/data

docker-compose up -d
```

Then look at the content of your /data dir on your container using

```
docker exec n4j ls -al /data
```

This gives me

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Sep 12 11:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 51 root root 4096 Sep 12 11:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 12 11:16 databases
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 12 11:16 dbms
```

Comment: I've just tried it and the db is created. I'll put more details in my answer.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, it's likely caused by the $HOME var. Add your `docker info` and `docker version` to your question.

Comment: yes it works now. can you confirm that when I add nodes in my db, they are stored in my local data folder instead of the container folder?

Comment: If you're using Docker for Mac/windows or Docker Toolbox, your local User directory is mounted on the host so it will be accessible. You can easily test it by starting a one off container and looking at the content of the volume. `docker run --rm -v $HOME/neo4jdev/data:/temp alpine ls -al /temp`